# php threads with oracle error: two-task save area overflow

Tags: php, multithreading, oracle, oracle12c

I have enabled Threads in php so i can do multiple task at the same time, the goal is to extract data from an Oracle server (12C) to my local.

Why on threads?? Because at some point we spect to handle around 500 million records between a couple of tables so i want to extract the data at the same time to try minimize process time.

This is my php code:

```
<?php

//*************Thread 1
class table1Class extends Thread{
  public $bdconn;
  public function __construct($bdconn) {
    $this->bdconn = $bdconn;
  }

  public function run(){
    $stTable1 = oci_parse($this->bdconn, 'INSERT INTO TABLE_1 
      SELECT * FROM TABLE_1@DBLINK');
    oci_execute($stTable1); //******* LINE 13
  }
}

//***********Thread 2
class table2Class extends Thread{
  public $bdconn;
  public function __construct($bdconn) {
    $this->bdconn = $bdconn;
  }

  public function run(){
    $stTable2 = oci_parse($this->bdconn, 'INSERT INTO TABLE_2
      SELECT * FROM TABLE_2@DBLINK');
    oci_execute($stTable2); //****** LINE 27
  }
}


function pad($val) {
  return ($val > 9) ? $val : "0".$val;
}


$start= microtime(true); //time

require_once '../../lib/bd_con.php';
$bdconn=  conBd(); //open connection

/**********TRUNCATE LOCAL TABLES*/
$trunPref=  oci_parse($bdconn, 'TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_1');
oci_execute($trunPref);

$trunCruz=  oci_parse($bdconn, 'TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_2');
oci_execute($trunCruz);
/************END*/


//***********BEGIN THREADS
$table1 = new table1Class($bdconn);
$table1->start();

$table2 = new table2Class($bdconn);
$table2->start();


//*********WAINT FOR THREADS TO END
$table1->join();
$table2->join();


oci_close($bdconn); //close connection

//PRINT TIME INFORMATION
$end= microtime(true); //al final del archivo
$tiempo_segundos = number_format($end-$start,4);
echo pad(((Int)($tiempo_segundos/60))).":".pad(((Int)($tiempo_segundos%60)))." minutes";
```

And this is the error i get whe executing:

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current
> operation in C:\xampp\htdocs...\file.php on line 13
>
> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-03117: two-task save area overflow in
> C:\xampp\htdocs...\file.php on line 27

A small explanation of what the code is intended to do is: truncate my local tables and execute the two threads to insert the data again from oracle server using dblink.

I'll be grateful if someone can give an idea how to fix this please.

Comment: Create 2 connections: access to shared resources must be synchronised unless they are thread-safe or you must not share them at all.

Comment: I made it work using two connections with different users, if declare 2 oci_connect with the same user won´t work.

Is there a way to instance the database connection with the same user multiple times in the same file??

Comment: I have the same error, but in python

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but in python. Apparently, it is produced when two different threads are sharing the same oracle connection.

By "the same" I am referring to the exactly same connection object: if you open two different connections (despite they have the same user and password) there wouldn't be any problem.

To avoid this problem **use just one connection object per thread**: you can accomplish this use connection pooling also.